# Creating new Outlook mail item via javascript and vbscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, vbscript, outlook

I'm creating a custom HTML page with a button which generates and sends an email based on the parameters the user chose. The user chooses a team (decides the "to" address of the email), CC, subject, body, etc.

I have each of these variables expressed in Javascript because I was initially using Mailto: to make the email, but I want to format the body with HTML and send the email automatically upon pressing the button, so I decided to go with VBScript instead of Mailto.

Here's my code:

```
<script>
  var emailTo = $("#teamName").val();
  var emailCC = $("#CC").val();
  var emailSubject = $("#ticketNumber").val();
  var reason = $('#otherRadioBtn').is(':checked')?$("#otherFreeTextField").val():$(".reason:checked").val();
  var emailBody = "<html><body><p><b>Issue:</b> " + $("#issue").val() + "<p><b>Customer Contact Information:</b> " + $("#contactInformation").val() + "<p><b>Requested Action:</b> " + $(".requestedAction:checked").val() + "<p><b>Reason:</b> " + reason + "<p><b>AWorkaround Available?</b> " + $(".workaround:checked").val() + "</body></html>";
</script>

<script type="text/vbscript">
  Function sendEmail()
    Dim oApp As New Outlook.Applications
    Dim oEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    oEmail.To = emailTo
    oEmail.CC = emailCC
    oEmail.Subject = emailSubject
    oEmail.HTMLBody = emailBody
    With oEmail
      If Not IsNull(.To) And Not IsNull(.Subject) And Not ISNull(.HTMLBody) Then
        .Send
        Msgbox "Escalation sent successfully!"
      Else
        MsgBox "Please complete all of the fields."
      End If
    End With
  End Function
</script>

<input type="submit" value="Generate email" onclick="sendEmail()">
```

When I click the Generate Email button, nothing happens. I suspect it has something to do with my VBSCript code, in particular the variables I gave it.

This is for my team in my organization, we all use Outlook and IE.

Comment: First and most obvious problem is `Dim oApp As New Outlook.Applications` which should be `Dim oApp : Set oApp = New Outlook.Application` as you can't type declare variables in vbscript

Answer (score 0):

@Dave is correct about the type declaration, but the correct syntax is

```
Dim oApp : Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Also, you can't use named constants in VBScript. You have to either set the constant or send its value. Either:

```
Const olMailItem = 0
Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
```

or

```
Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(0)
```

Comment: Also: Outlook doesn't like it when you use the `.Send` method via code. Users may likely get a security warning about a program trying to send an e-mail message on their behalf. It might be better to show the email to the user, and the user can then send it. But then, of course, why not simply generate a `MAILTO` link?